# 404 page showing phishing. how to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, phishing

I am using wordpress and I needed a application which is made with codeigniter.
I was useing facebook sdk 4 to let my user login but after few day it got phishing by google chrome. Then I delete the application, now it's 404 page.... I request a review in google but no help.

my only one directory got effected by phishing where the application was located else everything is fine. I have talked with google forum but they are all idiots saying i have problem in my 404 page. if the problem in 404 page then my hole site would effected not one directory. I am using popup add from www.popads.net
I think popup is not the problem can i am useing popup in my full site....

http://www.ogx1.com/addme

this link will show 404 but if you add a / it will show phishing... i have no idea what is wrong

http://www.ogx1.com/addme/

guys need help if you can suggest me with any thing....
and can you tell me how many day google take to remove the flag??

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that the user activity in that page have caused it to be blocked. If users post links to pishing websites, your website will be blocked as well.

If your pages had comments or posts, use CodeIgniter's XSS Clean or any equivalent WP function to prevent malicious code/URLs from being posted by users/bots.

I'm not sure if google will ever unlock the page, so you should consider renaming the "addme" page.

Regards.

Comment: there is no content but still it's locked. If I open a new domain and redirect my hole site what will happen?? will my new domain be locked?? will it have any bad effect on my new domain??

Comment: Using a new domain should fix that problem. Just take the necessary precautions as I described in the answer. I also recommend changing the IP address of your website. Cheers.